# Flask-Jinja2 FOR statement not printing assumed values

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I'm a newbie experimenting with Flask/Jinja2 and SQL-Alchemy.

I have a question about html output when using Jinja2 templating.

My view function looks like this:

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template
from init_database import init_db
from app.models import Provider

@app.route('/update')
def update():
    provider = Provider.query.get_or_404(1)
    return render_template("update.html", provider=provider)
```

And my template looks like this:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="page">
    <ul>
    { % for provider in prov %}
        <li>
            {{ provider.nzbprovider }}
            {{ provider.rssfeed }}
        </li>
    { % endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

When I run the app, the out looks like this in the browser:

```
{ % for provider in prov %}
Peter Johnson
Michael Manning
{ % endfor %}
```

Why does it display the Jinja tags? What have I forgotten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have spaces in the Jinja tag delimiters:  Change `{ %` (with a space) to `{%` (with no space)